# Laravel Echo opens a connection before using any commands

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

I just started using Laravel Echo (with `laravel-websockets`) and I noticed a new connection is made to the websocket server for every browsing session (every tab), and that is before I even use any `echo` commands!
I wonder if this is the normal behavior of the Echo library ?

I'm planning to use websockets for admin dashboard only, and having an unnecessary open connection for every guest user is probably a big concern.

And it's not just the open connection, a series of ping/pong messages will be happening between the client and the server. I believe having these amount of request for every public visitor may cause networking & resources issues on the server.

My `bootstrap.js` file :

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_HOST,
    wsPort: Number(process.env.MIX_PUSHER_HOST_PORT),
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

Anyone can shed some lights on this ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use PrivateChannel or PresenceChannels to limit access just for Auth users. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#presence-channels. Once Echo define. You can use a js file just in admin view with Echo.join()...